# UITableView animated scrolling between sections while temporarily removing excessive cells for simplified animation

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

In our app the user is able in a intuitive way to scroll to next section in the tableview using some controls outside the tableview. Some sections contains many cells and scrolling animated does not look smooth because there is just too many cells to scroll by. For the sake of a simple and understood animation we want to temporarily remove the cells which are excessive for the animation.

Say the user is on

```
section.0 row.5 out of 100 rows
```

and he want to scroll to

```
section.1 row.0 out of 100 rows
```

Then we want to sort of skip all the excessive cells while scrolling animated. So we temporarily want to remove all cells between

```
e.g. section.0 row.10 untill section.0 row.98
```

Any ideas how I can get by this? I'm sure this could be usefull to others as well. I want to do this as clean as possible.

Comment: Are you re-using cells or is each one unique?

Comment: I am reusing cells. Will it make a difference?

Comment: You might be able use re-usable facade cells and just reload the data where you're going to be animating.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. But what I am more interested in knowing how to setup the whole system. I've added an attempt as a answer, but I'm not sure if that is the way to go..

Answer (score 0):

I have a few ideas on how you might be able to handle this.  First is to reload the cells of interest, and return a lightweight cell.  You might be able to use `CGBitmapContext` to copy the image data into a "facade" cell instead of the real one.  Second would be to reload the data for the `UITableView` and then not return the data for the rows of interest.  Third is to actually remove the rows.  Another idea might be to disable interaction while you're animating.

**Reload rows:**

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPathOfYourCell, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

**Insert/Delete rows:**

```
[tableView beginUpdate];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:*arrayOfIndexPaths* withRowAnimation:*rowAnimation*];
[tableView endUpdate];

[tableView beginUpdate];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:*arrayOfIndexPaths* withRowAnimation:*rowAnimation*];
[tableView endUpdate];
```

**Disable Interaction:**

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an early attempt. I feel this is a bit messy..

Self is subclass of UITableView

```
- (void)scrollAndSkipCellsAnimatedToTopOfSection:(NSUInteger)section
{
    CGRect sectionRect = [self rectForHeaderInSection:section];
    CGPoint targetPoint = sectionRect.origin;
    CGFloat yOffsetDiff = targetPoint.y - self.contentOffset.y;
    BOOL willScrollUpwards = yOffsetDiff > 0;

    if(willScrollUpwards)
    {
        [self scrollAndSkipCellsAnimatedUpwardsWithDistance:fabs(yOffsetDiff)];
    }
    else
    {
        [self scrollAndSkipCellsAnimatedDownwardsWithDistance:fabs(yOffsetDiff)];
    }
}

- (void)scrollAndSkipCellsAnimatedUpwardsWithDistance:(CGFloat)distance
{
    // when going upwards contentOffset should decrease

    CGRect rectToRemove = CGRectMake(0,
                             self.contentOffset.y + (self.bounds.size.height * 1.5) - distance,
                             self.bounds.size.width,
                             distance - (self.bounds.size.height * 2.5));

    BOOL shouldRemoveAnyCells = rectToRemove.size.height > 0;

    if(shouldRemoveAnyCells)
    {
        // property on my subclass of uitableview
        // these indexes may span over several sections
        self.tempRemoveIndexPaths = [self indexPathsForRowsInRect:rectToRemove];
    }

    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    [self beginUpdates];
    [self deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:self.tempRemoveIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self endUpdates];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];

    [self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.contentOffset.y - distance) animated:YES];
}

// And then I would probably have to put some logic into
// - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;


- (void)scrollAndSkipCellsAnimatedDownwardsWithDistance:(CGFloat)distance
{

}
```